# How to index and assign elements in a tensor using identical call signatures?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, matrix, variable-assignment

OK, I've been googling around for too long, I'm just not sure what to call this technique, so I figured it's better to just ask here on SO. Please point me in the right direction if this has an obvious name and/or solution I've overlooked.

For the laymen: a *tensor* is the logical extension of the matrix, in the same way a matrix is the logical extension of the vector. A vector is a rank-1 tensor (in programming terms, a 1D array of numbers), a matrix is a rank-2 tensor (a 2D array of numbers), and a rank-N tensor is then simply an N-D array of numbers.

Now, suppose I have something like this Tensor class:

```
template<typename T = double> // possibly also with size parameters
class Tensor
{
  private: 
    T *M;  // Tensor data (C-array)
           // alternatively, std::vector<T> *M 
           // or std::array<T> *M 
           // etc., or possibly their constant-sized versions
           // using Tensor<>'s template parameters

  public: 

    ... // insert trivial fluffy stuff here 

    // read elements
    const T & operator() (size_t a, size_t b) const {
        ... // error checks etc.
        return M[a + rows*b];
    }

    // write elements
    T & operator() (size_t a, size_t b) {
        ... // error checks etc.
        return M[a + rows*b];
    }

    ... 

};
```

With these definitions of `operator()(...)`, indexing/assign individual elements then has the same call signature:

```
Tensor<> B(5,5);
double a = B(3,4);   // operator() (size_t,size_t) used to both GET elements
B(3,4) = 5.5;        // and SET elements
```

It is fairly trivial to extend this up to arbitrary tensor rank. But what I'd like to be able to implement is a more high-level way of indexing/assigning elements:

```
Tensor<> B(5,5);
Tensor<> C = B( Slice(0,4,2), 2 );  // operator() (Slice(),size_t) used to GET elements
B( Slice(0,4,2), 2 ) = C;           // and SET elements 
         // (C is another tensor of the correct dimensions)
```

I am aware that `std::valarray` (and many others for that matter) does a very similar thing already, but it's not my objective to just *accomplish* the behavior; my objective here is to learn how to **elegantly**, **efficiently** and **safely** add the following functionality to my `Tensor<>` class:

```
// Indexing/assigning with Tensor<bool>
B( B>0 ) += 1.0;   

// Indexing/assigning arbitrary amount of dimensions, each dimension indexed 
// with either Tensor<bool>, size_t, Tensor<size_t>, or Slice()
B( Slice(0,2,FINAL), 3, Slice(0,3,FINAL), 4 ) = C; 

// double indexing/assignment operation
B(3, Slice(0,4,FINAL))(mask) = C;  // [mask] == Tensor<bool>

.. etc.
```

Note that it's my intention to use `operator[]` for non-checked versions of `operator()`. Alternatively, I'll stick more to the `std::vector<>` approach of using `.at()` methods for checked versions of `operator[]`. Anyway, this is a design choice and besides the issue right now.

I've conjured up the following incomplete "solution". This method is only really manageable for vectors/matrices (rank-1 or rank-2 tensors), and has many undesirable side-effects:

```
// define a simple slice class
Slice () 
{ 
  private:
    size_t 
        start, stride, end; 

  public: 
    Slice(size_t s, size_t e) : start(s), stride(1), end(e) {}
    Slice(size_t s, size_t S, size_t e) : start(s), stride(S), end(e) {}
    ...

};

template<typename T = double>
class Tensor
{
    ... // same as before

  public:       

    // define two operators() for use with slices:     

    // version for retrieving data
    const Tensor<T> & operator() (Slice r, size_t c) const {
        // use slicing logic to construct return tensor
        ...
        return M;
    {

    // version for assigning data
    Sass operator() (Slice r, size_t c) {
        // returns Sass object, defined below
        return Sass(*this, r,c);
    }

  protected:

    class Sass 
    {
        friend class Tensor<T>;

     private:        
        Tensor<T>& M;
        const Slice &R;
        const size_t c;

      public:

        Sass(Tensor<T> &M, const Slice &R, const size_t c)
            : M(M)
            , R(R)
            , c(c)
        {}

        operator Tensor<T>() const { return M; }

        Tensor<T> & operator= (const Tensor<T> &M2) {
            // use R/c to copy contents of M2 into M using the same 
            // Slice-logic as in "Tensor<T>::operator()(...) const" above
            ...

            return M;
        }

    };
```

But this just feels wrong...

For each of the indexing/assignment methods outlined above, I'd have to define a separate `Tensor<T>::Sass::Sass(...)` constructor, a new `Tensor<T>::Sass::operator=(...)`, and a new `Tensor<T>::operator()(...)` for each and every such operation. Moreover, the `Tensor<T>::Sass::operators=(...)` would need to contain much of the same stuff that's already in the corresponding `Tensor<T>::operator()(...)`, and making everything suitable for a `Tensor<>` of *arbitrary rank* makes this approach quite ugly, way too verbose and more importantly, completely unmanageable.

So, I'm under the impression there is a much more effective approach to all this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you should have the vector/matrix/tensor dimensions as template parameters. A slice of a tensor is simply a matrix with one dimension of the tensor set to 1. A similar approach was used here: [vmmlib tensor3 class](https://github.com/VMML/vmmlib/blob/master/include/vmmlib/tensor3.hpp), where 2D matrices are used as tensor slices.

Comment: @Wilbert: Sure, that indeed is one way to go, some would contend it is the "better" way. But it would not depracate the `Slice()` class above; a generator for indices like `[1, 3, 5, 7, ...]` is a functionality not inherently provided by what you suggest.

Comment: Indeed. But I would suggest that you rather create a function of your tensor that generates a matrix that represents a slice - just because you use the Matrix class doesn't mean you don't have slice generation functionality.

Comment: @Wilbert: Ah, you mean to say `Slice` == wrapper around `Matrix<T>`? I could go for that...Regardless, the main problem remains :)

Comment: No, not a wrapper. A slice is simply a matrix (which it is, conceptually)...and since it is a matrix, you use the matrix class for it :). To generate the slice, you probably have a function: Matrix Tensor::MakeSlice(..). To store the slice, Tensor::SetSlice(const Matrix&, ...). If you wrap the matrix, you will have to GetMatrix() all the time to use it, or write similar additional code.

Comment: @Wilbert: On second thought, you'd always have to *explicitly generate* the slice-matrix when implementing it like this...that doesn't seem very efficient. If a `Slice()` were to only store the (start,end,stride), an indexing operator can *infer* what to do without needing the (potentially large) memory overhead of explicit indices.

Comment: It depends what you need it for. I assumed that you will compute 'stuff' with it, that is, that most values in the slice are accessed multiple times. With a matrix, it might fit into L3 cache, which a full tensor in usual sizes for sure will not. Obviously, you would have to test the actual performance. But yes, you could make a SliceRef class with 3 uints and a tensor pointer, but actually doing something with this SliceRef will be costly.

Comment: Note that if the slice _doesn't_ generate the result, you could take several different slices, then mutate the matrix, and your initial slices will have changed value. Is that what the user will want/expect?

Answer (score 3):

First of all I'd like to point out some design issues:

```
T & operator() (size_t a, size_t b) const;
```

suggests you can't alter the matrix through this method, because it's `const`. But you are giving back a nonconst reference to a matrix element, so in fact you *can* alter it. This only compiles because of the raw pointer you are using. I suggest to use `std::vector` instead, which does the memory management for you and will give you an error because vector's const version of `operator[]` gives a const reference like it should.

Regarding your actual question, I am not sure what the parameters of the Slice constructor should do, nor what a Sass object is meant to be (I am no native speaker, and "Sass" gives me only one translation in the dictionary, meaning sth. like "impudence", "impertinence").
However, I suppose with a slice you want to create an object that gives access to a subset of a matrix, defined by the slice's parameters.

I would advice against using `operator()` for every way to access the matrix. op() with two indices to access a given element seems natural. Using a similar operator to get a whole matrix to me seems less intuitive.

Here's an idea: make a Slice class that holds a reference to a Matrix and the necessary parameters that define which part of the Matrix is represented by the Slice. That way a Slice would be something like a proxy to the Matrix subset it defines, similar to a pair of iterators which can be seen as a proxy to a subrange of the container they are pointing to. Give your Matrix a pair of `slice()` methods (const and nonconst) that give back a Slice/ConstSlice, referencing the Matrix you call the method on. That way, you can even put checks into the method to see if the Slice's parameters make sense for the Matrix it refers to. If it makes sense and is necessary, you can also add a conversion operator, to convert a Slice into a Matrix of its own.

Overloading operator() again and again and using the parameters as a mask, as linear indices and other stuff is more confusing than helping imo. `operator()` is slick if it does something natural which everybody expects from it. It only obfuscates the code if it is used everywhere. Use named methods instead.

Comment: +0: spot on about the misplaced `const`. Also moving the entire logic to `Slice()` is something I will look into, hadn't considered that. The term `Sass` is not intended to be a word; it's a contraction of "Slice" and "assignment", poorly chosen I admit, and will probably need to be renamed. Regarding the intuitive nature of multiple versions of `operator()` really depends on context and application, doesn't it? A blanket statement like the one you make is a bit misplaced...

Comment: Also, I intend to use `operator()` for bounds-checked versions of the `operators[]`, or, to stay in line with `std::vector`, implement a `.at()` method for all `operators[]` I define. More importantly, I just gave those examples to illustrate why I think my approach is flawed, not to actually use or imeplement them :) Also, regarding usage of `std::vector` instead of C-arrays; well, that also depends...`std::vector` is versatile, flexible, dynamic, managed, ubiquitous, etc., but perhaps not the best suited thing for computationally/memory intensive tasks...I'll give it a thought.

Comment: if you know the size of your matrix in every dimension you could use std::array instead of the vector. However, your `T*M` suggests you allocate the memory dynamically, and `std::vector` is just that - a dynamic C-array, wrapped into a class template harness providing RAII and other features that don't impact performance if you don't use them.

Comment: Having a huge overload set of `operator()` at least disregards the expressiveness of writing (and reading!) method names, independent of the context. Multiple overloads should at least return the same kind of entity, not a single entry here and a whole matrix there. Otherwise you will have to look up the type of the arguments to know the type of the results. Correct me if I am wrong, but *not* using methods that explicitly say what they are doing will gain you nothing but to save you a bit of typing.

Comment: Have a look at the [doc of valarray](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/valarray/operator%5B%5D/); it does quite the same thing with `operator[]`. It's really a matter of *taste* I'd say...

Comment: Note that I've edited my question to better reflect what I meant to ask...OK, now, if I understand you correctly -- your advice is to create a `Slice()` class that holds a ref to the `Tensor<>` and the information necessary to index/assign the intended subset, something like `Slice(M, 2,3,4, 0,1,5) = 1;` or so (where `2,3,4` is for the row-slice, `0,1,5` for the column slice. Is this what you meant? In that case, I find it hard to extend to arbitrary dimension in the sense that `Slice(M, 2,3,4, 0,1,5, 3,4,FINAL, 0,1,8) += M_PI;` for a rank-4 tensor is a little harsh on the eyes...

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a note to follow up my comment:

```
Tensor<bool> T(false);
// T (whatever its rank) contains all false
auto lazy = T(Slice(0,4,2));
// if I use lazy here, it will be all false
T = true;
// now T contains all true
// if I use lazy here, it will be all true
```

This *may* be what you want, or it might be unexpected.

In general, this can work cleanly with *immutable* tensors, but allowing mutation gives the same class of problem as COW strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow for your Tensor to implicitly be a double you can return only Tensors from your operator() overload.

```
operator double() { 
    return M.size() == 1 ? M[0] : std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(); 
};
```

That should allow for

```
double a = B(3,4);
Tensor<> a = B(Slice(1,2,3),4);
```

To get the operator() to work with multiple overloads with Slice and integer is another issue. I'd probably just use Slice and create another implicit conversion so integers can be Slice's, then maybe using the variable argument elipses.

```
const Tensor<T> & operator() (int numOfDimensions, ...)
```

Although the variable argument route is kind of a kludge best to just have 8 specializations for 1-8 parameters of Slice.

Comment: Hmmm I feel this would create more chaos then it would solve...thanks though!